# How do I do a quick restart?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I've watched a few videos of people playing and it appears (without the footage being cut) that they're just pressing a button and it restarts the whole thing instantly in order to start with a specific item. Is this a program/macro? Is there a button I can press for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not pressing a button, it's **holding** a button (not tapping).

When you hold <kbd>r</kbd> for a couple of seconds, it will restart your run. (However this will not work for Eden, since it uses tokens to check if you may play him)

You can also hold the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for a few seconds to drop your trinket(s) and card(s) / pill(s)
(You may want to drop a certain trinket before going to a certain place

> Drop The left hand before going to the chest

### Controller

For controllers the controls are different (for example:
Holding <kbd>RT</kbd> (right trigger) will drop the trinkets and pills / cards.

And from seeing the [Reddit thread about controller support](http://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/2ltzsn/rebirths_controller_support_just_blew_me_away/):

> Unfortunately, I don't think the DS4 has a restart button enabled by default. So if I want to restart, I need to switch over to the keyboard for a second. Other than that, loving my DS4.

And

> No controller has binding for restart.

[Statement of developer on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/2lszaj/is_there_anyway_to_fast_restart_on_the_ps4vita/):

> We ran out of buttons. Maybe in an update.

Comment: Will holding  r work when I'm playing with a controller?

Comment: Updated the answer to add the controller information

Comment: With the controller plugged in, can I use the keyboard for restarting? If not, is there a way to use the keyboard for restart, then plug the controller back in and have it recognize it as the main one instead of player 2? I swear I've seen controller play with resets so I think it's possible.

Comment: @Crubleigh You should be able to use the keyboard when the controller is plugged in. Do you have an example (video) for me to double check? [Statement of developer on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/2lszaj/is_there_anyway_to_fast_restart_on_the_ps4vita/): `We ran out of buttons. Maybe in an update.` (1 month ago)

Comment: It's also possible to change the inputs of your controller with 3rd-party software (like [Xpadder](http://xpadder.com/)).

Comment: I tested reset with controller plugged in and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

hold both R3 and L3 for a few seconds

Answer (score -1):

There's currently no restart button on the PS4 console but Tyrone ( developer who worked on the game ) says maybe in a later update so hopes afterbirth will Come with a quick restart option :)